# How to apply css to three different classes hovering one of them

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.

```
<div class="start">start</div>
<div>middle-1</div>
<div>middle-2</div>
<div>middle-3</div>
...................
...................
<div>middle-n</div>
<div class="end">end</div>
```

I want to apply css to all div's when mouse hover the first div with class start.

Comment: use general sibling selector `~` like this `.start:hover ~ div {...}`

Comment: @vipin you want to style all the divs from `middle-1` to `middle-n` or include also the `.end`?

Comment: I'm lying it's possible! Do you want `.end` to be also affected, and what about divs after `.end`?

Comment: @vipin is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/745Xs/

Comment: yes i want to include .end also.

Comment: @king king but it will affect the following div's after .end if there is any.

Comment: The title refers to three classes. There are just two classes used in the code posted.

Comment: @vipin then you have to apply default style for the divs after `.end` like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/745Xs/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the current HTML structure you can use couple of sibling selectors for this.

```
.start:hover ~ div {
    color: red; /* styles you want to apply */
}
/* reset styles back for all other divs after .end */
.start:hover ~ .end ~ div {
    color: inherit;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3c6V6/1/

However I would recommend to change HTML structure if you can. For example:

```
<div class="start">start</div>
<div class="middles">
    <div>middle-1</div>
    <div>middle-2</div>
    <div>middle-3</div>
    <div>middle-n</div>
    <div class="end">end</div>
</div>
<div>after-1</div>
<div>after-2</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.start:hover + .middles > div {
    color: red;
}
```

You would just have much more flexibility.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3c6V6/2/

Comment: thanks it works but what if I want to do the same in the opposite way,I want to apply css when hover .end

Comment: In this case you would better use Javascript for this. Sibling selectors don't work backward unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as putting a parent container around it, and putting the hover on that, or do you wish to single out some of the siblings directly?

In this case, try putting :hover on the parent container like this:

```
.parent:hover div {/*style*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for your second version found in the comments: **[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/7mjxz/1/)**

```
div.start:hover~div.middles div:not(.end) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

(This is for your original question):

```
div.start:hover~div:not(.end) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/7mjxz/)**

[This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) is where I found the information to do it. Didn't know there were so many CSS selectors.

Comment: Indeed, although it *does* meet the OP's original specifications, I didn't see the trail of comments changing the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523221/how-to-apply-css-to-three-different-classes-hovering-one-of-them/24523338#comment37970718_24523221

Comment: Like I said, if I didn't read the comments (which weren't there when I started), then I wouldn't know that the question changed